# Jolt alternative for head to find first non empty non null string in json array

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

Is there any alternative `head` to transform and get first non empty or non null value from JSON array. similar to `head(/part/subline/sublineGrouop/sublineGroupTP/detailsGP/dtlLine/details/code)`
should return `US`

```
{
  "part": {
    "subline": {
      "sublineGroup": {
        "property1": "test",
        "proerty2": "tes2",
        "sublineGroupTP": {
          "detailsGP": [
            {
              "dtlLine": {
                "details": {
                  "code": null
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "dtlLine": {
                "details": {
                  "code": ""
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "dtlLine": {
                "details": {
                  "code": "US"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "dtlLine": {
                "details": {
                  "code": "UK"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Expected Output JSON

```
{
  "countryCode": "US"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to write the whole path(s) preceded by @ sign, except for the parts with arrays, in which you might use a conditional in order to get an array with non-null and non-blank components, then pick the first components of the array by the function such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@part.subline.sublineGroup.sublineGroupTP.detailsGP": {
        "*": { // the indexes of the "detailsGP" array
          "@dtlLine.details.code": { // the conditional for the code values starts here
            "": "", // blank values
            "*": {  // values with length > 0
              "$": "countryCode[]" // current key values which are the values 
                                   // arraywisely( [] ) inherited from the upper node, 
                                   // eg. the values of codes
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // in order to pick the first component from the array
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=firstElement(@(1,&))" // derive the value of the array( & ) 
                                   // from the current right-hand-side( 1 ) level
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following ***shift*** transformation.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "part": {
        "subline": {
          "sublineGroup": {
            "sublineGroupTP": {
              "detailsGP": {
                "*": {
                  "dtlLine": {
                    "details": {
                      "code": {
                        "": "", //Skip null and empty values.
                        "*": {
                          "@(2,&1)": "" //Group non-null values
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "0": "countryCode" // 1st item in the array.
    }
  }
]
```

[image]